# Segmentation fault after returning unique_ptr inside of pair from function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a factory that creates class instances from strings. KeyValueType is an abstract class, which will be passed to Map/Reduce functions.

```
class KeyValueType {
public:
    virtual void parse(const std::string &) = 0;

    virtual std::string to_string() const = 0;
};
```

Factories in code are getting from the shared library (to be able to config map/reduce functions from a remote computer).

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<KeyValueType> KeyValueTypeFactory::create() override {
    return std::make_unique<KeyValueType<T>>();
};
std::unique_ptr<KeyValueType> KeyValueTypeFactory::create(const std::string &str) override {
    std::unique_ptr<KeyValueType> ptr = this->create();
    ptr->parse(str);
    return ptr;
};
```

So, I have the next code, where I'm creating two objects key/value and returning them, as a pair of unique_ptr

```cpp
std::pair<std::unique_ptr<KeyValueType>, std::unique_ptr<KeyValueType>> 
get_key_value_from_json(const std::string &data, std::unique_ptr<KeyValueTypeFactory> &key_factory, std::unique_ptr<KeyValueTypeFactory> &value_factory) {
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt{};
    boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(dynamic_cast<std::stringstream &>(std::stringstream{} << data), pt);
    return { std::move(key_factory->create(pt.get("key", ""))),
             std::move(value_factory->create(pt.get("value", ""))) };
}
std::pair<std::unique_ptr<KeyValueType>, std::unique_ptr<KeyValueType>> blocking_get_result() {
        ... // Get json and config
        auto[key, value] = get_key_value_from_json(json, cfg->key_out_factory, cfg->value_res_factory);
        std::cout << "The result of Map/Reduce is " << value->to_string() << std::endl;
        return { std::move(key), std::move(value) };
}
int main() {
    auto[key, value] = blocking_get_result();
    std::cout << (value.get() == nullptr) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The result of Map/Reduce is " << value->to_string() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The actual problem is, that in `blocking_get_result()` function key and value are valid and virtual function `to_string()` is working correctly, but after returning pair from function to main `unique_ptr` is not null, but `to_string` throws Segmentation Fault. Also, `dynamic_cast` to a derived class is causing Segfault.

Comment: Valgrind is returning next message:


==4432== Invalid read of size 8
==4432==    at 0x115CA0: main (main.cpp:44)
==4432==  Address 0x4864c48 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==4432==
==4432==
==4432== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==4432==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4864C48
==4432==    at 0x115CA0: main (main.cpp:44)


44 line is the one, where a virtual method is called

Comment: This kind of error typically means that you try to dereference nullptr. Are you sure that both your factories are not nullptr? Also there's not enough information in the snippets you've provided to determine the real cause.

Comment: Does adding a virtual destructor to KeyValueType help?

Comment: @MarianSpanik, adding virtual destructor doesn't help.

Comment: @freakish, Both factories are not null. Also, blocking_get_result function result is correct and both pointers are not null, but after returning them to main they are not null also, but virtual functions don't work. What info do you need more ?

Comment: @Midren Except for the missing virtual destructor in the base type KeyValueType the code seems to be OK for me. Does your compiler produce any other warnings? Does the valgrind still complain with the virtual destructor? Can you create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by eliminating parts irrelevant to the problem (e.g. the JSON parsing) so people can copy+paste your code and run it?

Comment: The `std::move` in `std::move(key_factory->create(pt.get("key", "")))` is unneeded `create` already returns by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was, that getting config fulfilled by using `dlopen` and `dlsym` and wrapping result into shared_ptr. So shared library was freed in blocking_get_result. So in the main pointer in the vtable became invalid.